# How can I get pb2.py into excel?

Tags: python, excel, automation, protocol-buffers, proto

I am having a hard time with this. Is there a way to get a compiled protocol buffer file’s (pb2.py) contents into excel?

Comment: is there any code or attempt to make code and if so any errors that come with it ?  ideally https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks detail and a demonstration of your attempt to solve this problem, it is likely that it will be closed.

Presumably (!?) your intent is to start with serialized binary/wire format protocol buffer messages, unmarshal these into Python objects and then, using a Python package ([list](https://www.google.com/search?q=pypi+excel) that can interact with Excel, enter these objects as row into Excel.

The Python (`pb2.pby`) file generated by the protocol buffer compiler (`protoc`) from a `.proto` file, contains everything you need to marshal and unmarshal messages in the binary/wire format to Python objects that represent the messages etc. that are defined by the `.proto` file. The protocol buffer documentation is comprehensive and explains this well ([link](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#parsing-and-serialization)).

Once you've unmarshaled the data into one or more Python objects, you will need to use the Python package for Excel of your choosing to output these objects into the spreadsheet(s).

It is unclear whether you have flat or hierarchical data. If you have anything non-trivial, you'll also need to decide how to represent the structure in the spreadsheet's table-oriented structure.